# Duplicate results on inner join

Tags: sql, join

I've written the below query but I'm getting multiple duplicate rows in the results, please can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
       use Customers
     select customer_details.Customer_ID,
   customer_details.customer_name,
   metering_point_details.MPAN_ID,
   Agents.DA_DC_Charge

  from Customer_Details
   left join Metering_Point_Details
  on customer_details.customer_id = Metering_Point_Details.Customer_ID
 left join agents
 on customer_details.Customer_ID = agents.customer_id 

  order by customer_id
```

Comment: There might be nothing wrong. Depends on your table structure, example data and expected output which you don't show

Comment: Is every field duplicative?  Or only fields from a specific table.  If the latter, that would indicate that could mean you just have a one-to-many relationship between your tables in the join and that there are multiple records on one side for a matching record on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter, but you're not using an `INNER JOIN`.  Regardless, your unexpected rows indicate that your `JOIN` criteria is not specific enough to return your expected output.  You can use `SELECT DISTINCT` if your results are fully duplicative, and if you'd like to see why you're getting those duplicates you can just use `SELECT *` to see the full detail between the multiple rows that are returned using your `JOIN` criteria, which should help you either make your criteria more specific or show you that you've got duplicated records in one of the tables you're using in your `JOIN`.

With sample data we can dissect the problem more, but odds are you won't need it once you see why the rows are duplicated.